# Implications of changing column from not null to nullable in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have to change the username column in my database to nullable, which means everywhere in my code, I now have to check username.HasValue and change references to username to username.Value.  Is there anything I can do to avoid having to change all the references to username to username.Value?

Comment: I am not sure if you could do that on your database even :S making a column nullable for not nullable ? is it possible?

Comment: My column is initially marked as "not null".  I am changing it to "null" which means the column can contain a null value.  This is possible.

Comment: assuming that it is possible on sql server, update your edmx model from database. that would work. But I think, you want to avoid to get any exception because of the nullable filed. right?

Comment: I am sorry that I misread your question :S

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `username` is a `string` you don't have to change the type in your code since it's a reference type anyway which can be null or not null. `.HasValue` or `.Value` don't exist on a reference type. Perhaps you have to make checks like `if (username != null)` or `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))` sometimes but that's it.

Comment: but if ToString() method is used for that field, that would cause problem, right?

Comment: @tugberk: Which field do you mean? Using `ToString()` on a field which is a `string` anyway doesn't make much sense. Of course, if you would apply `ToString()` on a `string` which is `null` you'd get an exception. But the point is: Even if the column in the database is not nullable it doesn't make a string (or generally reference type) in your code not nullable. So it's always good practice to check for null before you access the string.

Comment: some guy uses ToString() for string values. my point was for that.